# What is the difference/use case for _: vs _ String: when writing functions

Tags: swift, syntax, structure

I'm learning swift and the _ symbol is giving me a lot of trouble. In the apple book "app development in swift" lesson #15 we learn to build structures. I am trying to understand the difference between using _: to represent an unnamed parameter and using _ String: to represent something(presumably another unnamed parameter but we are giving it a name?)

here is my example code:

```
    struct Rectangle {
        let width: Int
        let height: Int
        var area: Int {
            return width*height
        }

func biggerThan(_ rectangle: Rectangle) -> Bool {
    return area > rectangle.area
    }
}
```

Along the same lines as my main question i do not understand why this function works written as either `(_ rectangle: Rectangle)` or `(_:Rectangle)` without changing the return line of the code.

Comment: Your code won't compile if you change `(_ rectangle: Rectangle)` to `(_:Rectangle)`, as you use `rectangle` in the body.

Comment: hamish, i also thought it wouldnt. The xcode playground though compiled okay. the word rectangle changed from white to green but it still runs the code as expected.

Comment: Don't test in a playground – they're super buggy and unreliable. Test it in a real project, and you'll see that it doesn't compile.

Comment: i just ran it in xcode and you're correct! thank you, i didnt realize that was an issue in xcode/playgrounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that you are running into Swift version issues. In Swift 3, one of two syntax is required:

```
func foo(bar:String, bar2:Int) {
}

func foo(_ bar:String, bar2:String) {
}

func foo(bar:String, _ bar2:String) {
}

func foo(_ bar:String, _ bar2:Int) {
}
```

And the corresponding calls to this function are:

```
foo(bar: "Hello World", bar2: 1)
foo("Hello World", bar2: 1)
foo(bar: "Hello World", 1)
foo(bar: "Hello World", 1)
```

That is, and underscore in the signature means you do not declare it in your call.

**BUT** In all previous versions of Swift, the first parameter has an implied underscore, making the corresponding calls:

```
foo("Hello World", bar2: 1)
foo("Hello World", bar2: 1)
foo("Hello World", 1)
foo("Hello World", 1)
```

Also note that while you can consider the underscore to **explicitly** declare to not use a name, you can also **rename** things:

```
foo(bar myBar:String, bar2 myBar2:Int) {
    // internally refer to myBar and myBar2, not bar and bar2
}
```

And the call is:

```
foo(bar: "Hello World", bar2: 1)
```

Comment: thank you very much dfd, that clears up the situation for me